# UEFI boot is disabled, disabling Legacy boot does not work

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, uefi

On my computer, I enabled Legacy boot to use older operating systems (even though I did not install any). A few weeks later, I could not find UEFI boot on my hard drive. I get "Notebook Hard Drive" is my boot menu, but do not get "OS Boot Manager". Disabling legacy boot does not help. When I do, I get:

```
Boot Device Not Found

Please install an operating system on your hard disk.
Hard Disk (3F0)
F2   System Diagnostics

For more information, please visit: www.hp.com/go/techcenter/startup
```

When I look at the Boot Option Menu (accessible by pressing F9), it is blank. It reads:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                      Boot Manager
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Boot Option Menu


UP and Down to change option, Enter to select an option.
Press F10 for BIOS Setup Options, ESC to exit.
```

Not even the ability to select EFI file.

I have tried resetting BIOS settings, but it did not fix the issue.

I have Linux Mint 18.3 (Cinnamon 64-bit) installed. It came with Windows 8.1 from the factory. It can still boot Linux with Legacy boot enabled, even though it used to work on normal boot.

My computer is an HP 10 TS notebook computer, (model e010nr I think), with InsydeH2O BIOS version F.0A (16.010?) revision 3.7. System Board ID 21A9.

Comment: What boot options are you seeing in the BIOS?

Comment: In my BIOS setings, I see (normally) CD/DVD drive (disabled, no CD-DVD drive present), USB drive (allowed), Hard Drive (OS Boot Manager for UEFI, Notebook Hard Drive for Legacy). With normal boot, I see OS Boot Manager, Notebook Hard Drive, and Boot from EFI file. OS Boot Manager disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

There are BIOS level UEFI entries that need to exist for the boot process to know where your Windows Boot Manager lives.

With the board in UEFI only mode, look at your boot options. There should be an option to "Add new boot option". This allows you to edit the UEFI menu on your motherboard.

Without knowing the brand of your firmware I cannot provide better instructions. Please read the manual for your motherboard.

EXAMPLE:
https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Restoring_UEFI_boot_entry_via_motherboard_replacement_or_BIOS_update

Comment: I don't have a BIOS entry for "Add new boot option". :(

Comment: What model of motherboard do you have here?